# how to convert hbase binary foramtted data and load it into Pig?

Tags: hbase, apache-pig

I have a table in Hbase which is having more than 2000 rows, and it consists binary formatted data.Trying to load it into pig and do some data processing on it using PIG

**Sample hbase table data:-**

```
ROW                              COLUMN+CELL

\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x06\xA6 column=cd:cct, timestamp=1475738991531, value=Atlanta

\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x06\xA6 column=cd:cnt, timestamp=1475740226346, value=Network ICE Corp.

\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x06\xA6 column=cd:ct, timestamp=1475740596684, value=ISYI srl
```

I have tried as mentioned in this 
[HBaseStorage using Pig](https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.9.1/api/org/apache/pig/backend/hadoop/hbase/HBaseStorage.html) link

**Command:-**

```
C = load ‘hbase://companydetail’
   using org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.hbase.HBaseStorage('cd', '-loadKey true')
   as (rowkey:bytearray, cd:map[]);
```

But as it is having lot of binary data in it, given lot of weird symbols which can not be readable and understandable.

**sample output:-**

```
(�$f,[parent_ccnt#United States,parent_cid#
                                            /�,p
```

I have tried an another way using binaryconverter

```
a = load 'hbase://tablename' using org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.hbase.HBaseStorage('cd','-loadKey -caster HBaseBinaryConverter') as (rowKey:bytearray,cd:map[]);
```

but still getting the same as above sample output.
In my table it consists more than 42 columns with cd column family.
In those 42 columns lot of binary formatted data is there.

Please suggest me how can i read binaryforamtted data into pig.

Any help is appreciable.

Thank you,

Mohan.V

Comment: Your example is pretty much what I would expect from printing binary data to the console. What are you hoping to get as output?